# Is there any Visual Editor for MediaWiki that not depends on Parsoid?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm trying to install VisualEditor on a ordinary server hosting. But VisualEditor depends on Parsoid server. My hosting plan doesn`t allow to install another frameworks and apps.

Is there any VisualEditor for MediaWiki that not depends on Parsoid? Is it possible to install VisualEditor withou Parsoid?

Answer (score -1):

Apparently it might be possible to get Extension:VisualEditor running on an  ordinary server hosting, by running Parsoid remotely on Heroku.com. There is a walk through on MediaWiki.org at the page [VisualEditor on a shared host](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/VisualEditor_on_a_shared_host).